# Chained XPath axes with trailing `[1]` or `[last()]` predicates

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

This question is specifically about using XPath in XSLT 2.0 and Saxon.

### XPaths ending with `[1]`

For XPaths like

```
following-sibling::foo[1]
descendant::bar[1]
```

I take it for granted that Saxon will not iterate over the entire axis but stop when it finds the first matching node - crucial in situations like:

```
following-sibling::foo[some:expensivePredicate(.)][1]
```

I assume that this is also the case for XPaths like this:

```
(following-sibling::foo/descendant::bar)[1]
```

I.e. Saxon will not compile the entire set of nodes matching `following-sibling::foo/descendant::bar` before picking the first one in the set. Rather, it will (even for chained axes) stop at the first matching node.

### XPaths ending with `[last()]`

Now it gets interesting. When going "backwards" in the tree, I assume that XPaths like

```
preceding-sibling::foo[1]
```

work just as efficiently as their `following-sibling` equivalents. But what happens when chaining axes, e.g.

```
(preceding-sibling::foo/descendant::bar)[last()]
```

As we need to use `[last()]` here instead of `[1]`,

- will Saxon compile the entire set of nodes to count them to get a numeric value for `last()`?
- Or will it be smart and stop iterating the `preceding-sibling` axis when it found a matching descendant?
- Or will it be even more clever and iterate the `descendant` axis in reverse to more efficiently find the last descendant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon has a variety of strategies for evaluating `last()`. When used as a predicate, meaning `[position()=last()]`, it is generally translated to an internal function `[isLast()]` which can be evaluated by a single-item lookahead. (So in your example of `(preceding-sibling::foo /descendant::bar)[last()]`, it doesn't build the node-set in memory, rather it reads the nodes one by one and when it hits the end, returns the last one it found).

In other cases, particularly when used in XSLT match patterns, Saxon will convert `child::x[last()]` to `child::x[not(following-sibling::x)]`.

When none of these approaches work, for many years Saxon had two strategies for evaluating `last()` depending on the expression it was applied to: (a) sometimes it would evaluate the expression twice, counting nodes the first time and returning them the second time; (b) in other cases it would read all the nodes into memory. We've recently encountered cases where strategy (a) fails: see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3122, and so we're always doing (b).

The `last()` expression is potentially expensive and it should be avoided where possible. For example the classic "insert a separator between adjacent items" which is often written

```
xx
if (position() != last()) sep
```

is much better written as

```
if (position() != 1) sep
xx
```

i.e. instead of inserting the separator after every item except the last, insert it before every item except the first. Or use `string-join`, or `xsl:value-of/@separator`.

Comment: "The last() expression is potentially expensive" - that was my hunch that I hoped could be eliminated. It seems looking backwards with `(preceding-sibling::foo/descendant::bar)[last()]` might perform with O(n²) when applied to each element in a large data set. For my application, an alternative might be possible based on a key with a forward-looking `use` attribute, which would trade quadratic performance for linear memory usage. Still not ideal on large data sets, but manageable.

Comment: Any use of axes such as following[-sibling] or preceding[-sibling] when applied in a loop is liable to have quadratic performance, and in general the predicate `[last()]` isn't going to make it better. You also need to think about whether there will be a sort into document order - looking at the execution plan with -explain can be revealing.

Comment: Probably depends on the structure of the data, right? I guess I can assume linear performance for the query `(following-sibling::foo/descendant::bar)[1]` when I know that **1.** the first `following-sibling` with a matching descendant is at most, say, 5 nodes away (independent of how large the total data set is), and **2.** the size of each queried descendant axis is roughly constant (again, independent of how large the total data set is).